# Copy parallel created .zip files to a location after they are created

Tags: linux, command-line, bash

I use the following command to zip all files in a directory parallel:

```
cd /volume1/Backup/VHDX; for i in */; do zip -0 -r "${i%/}.zip" "$i" & done; wait
```

after all the zips are created, I move them to a NTFS formatted USB Drive like so:

```
cd /volume1/Backup/VHDX; find . -name "*.zip" -exec cp {} /volumeUSB1/usbshare \;
```

I was wondering If I could move each .zip directly to the target location, after it's created (so add the copy to the first command), instead of creating all the zips first and only after all are created start to copy them. Is there a way?

Directly creating the zips on the USB drive is super slow (it's a lot of data that gets zipped), that's why I'm creating it first locally and only then move it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's un-crumple your oneliner first:

```
cd /volume1/Backup/VHDX
for i in */; do
    zip -0 -r "${i%/}.zip" "$i" &
done
wait
```

Now move the files after `zip` is done:

```
cd /volume1/Backup/VHDX
for i in */; do
    zip -0 -r "${i%/}.zip" "$i"
    mv "${i%/}.zip" /volumeUSB1/usbshare &
done
wait
```

But now we're zipping only one directory at a time, possibly moving completed files simultaneously. We can work around this by using a subshell:

```
cd /volume1/Backup/VHDX
for i in */; do
    (zip -0 -r "${i%/}.zip" "$i" && mv "${i%/}.zip" /volumeUSB1/usbshare) &
done
wait
```

Alternatively, you could use `pigz` rather than `zip` to compress one file at a time, but using multiple CPU threads.

Comment: I have to One-Line it because it is an Argument in a PowerShell Script (`Invoke-SSHCommand -SessionID $SessionId -Command "Bash Command"`). Maybe I can also have it multiline I'll try that but if I can't would this re-crumple work? `cd /volume1/Backup/VHDX; for i in */; do (zip -0 -r "${i%/}.zip" "$i" && mv "${i%/}.zip" /volumeUSB1/usbshare) & done; wait` ?

Comment: Yup, that looks about right